# Why can't Google find the structured data on most of my indexed pages?

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data, schema.org

I have a website with approximately 30,000 pages.
Google index is OK, almost all pages are indexed, but in Structured data I see only 48 pages detected for schema.org.
Schema.org is identical of whole website.

**My question is why there is so big difference between indexed pages and detected with markup pages?**

Especially I worked hard to implement all suitable schemas for my website and now Google doesn't detect them.

Indexed pages - more than 27,000
[image: Structured data in Webmaster tools - 48 pages]

Pages with schema.org - 48
[image: Indexed pages in Webmaster tools - more than 27,000]

Comment: Webmaster Tools can be slow to report findings as its not real time, additionally it can take several crawls too. The important question is how many of your URLS does Google scan a month, I very much doubt 27,000, since I would expect to see a larger number. Google will always index and update the most popular of pages as these get crawled more often, some urls that have not been updated for months to years could take days, weeks or even months to update..

Comment: To update what @bybe has said (one up-vote on the comment). Google has a TTL style metric for each page. If the page is new or does not update often, Google will not visit it often. If the page is fresh and changes often, then the TTL time for the page will decrease over time and Google will visit the page more often. Freshness is an important metric in your scenario. If your site is standard in freshness, then it can take quite a bit of time for Google to discover the change. If your site is new, then it may test freshness with some sample head requests.

Comment: In my case this is a new website - this can be seen from the Indexed pages graphic  - it starts August 2014.
bybe - I don't ask for a crawled pages, but for Indexed.
And I can expect that points that you both noticed, but I'm asking for the difference between Indexed pages and Pages with schema markup.
While the content can be changed often or not, schema is a part of HTML structure.
And this question is very important to me because I start to work hard with schema.org for every my project as it is recommended by Google.

Comment: As I said it can take several crawls and it can take longer for it to appear in Webmaster Tools. It also takes longer for those schema to appear actually in the search engines i.e stars, in-stock- pricing and other perks that appear within search results (generally 2-3months). As long as your code checks out ok in rich snippet test there's little you can do... just tell customers that it takes 2-3months and you should never promise rich data appear actually in the results as Google doesn't always return the data in actual results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how it works based on sites we have released recently + a couple that have ran awhile.

Assuming its a new site using all out Schema.org as well as fallback data-vocab for crumbs and reviews datas, you should expect at least a 3 month lag time. You will see the Google webmaster tools schema reports doing nothing -- no new reviews, no new pages....even spikes then drops in counts or false alarms. Dont worry its just GADHD. One day in month 2(ish) you may see all the counts start fill in, level out, and stabilize. You may see the fallback data-vocab SERP widgets activate on trafficked/fresh pages. A month from this point, the schema.org SERP widgets should activate assuming there are no errors in GWT. You may notice back and forth, especially for reviews, price, etc during this time. One day they will be on, another off. One query on, another off. Eventually the SERPs will stabilize, but its possible that not all will activate in SERPS for all queries/views/etc.

As closetnoc pointed out in a comment for original question, the RDF triggers from fresh focal data/pages. It may take much longer than 3 months for those buried pages that never get hits, possibly up to a year for the really stale ones. Its a good idea to freshen up the areas that you want to trigger rich SERP widgets. Google will show they are indexed-RDF in GWT, ready to rock n roll, but the actual SERP widgets will not activate until the trigger allows. This trigger is fresh/traffic/interest/searches to your "already indexed" RDF pages.

Just be patient and expect to see alot of fluactions and inconsistancies. Thats just how the RDF bot index rolls with the prediction engine + pop queries I guess.

Comment: Re-visiting this answer: It appears as if Google+ logged in status combined with G+ local for biz has an effect on how fast your SERPS show structured data. Out on a limb, they seem to be tracking social + local interest at SERP level and seem to be more liberal in the rich snippets they show there. Example, review stars may show to a G+ user and any non-G+ user in your locality. Whereas, it may take another month for the same stars to show for the rest of the non-logged-in-non-local world. Moral of the comment: make sure you set up G+ local for your site(s) then verify as publisher too.

Comment: Note that my webmaster tools started showing my structured data 6 days after it going live on my site so this may have now improved